# ActionLink to show parameters in URL instead of querystring mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I need this url `http://localhost:53249/Admin/EditPosts/1/Edit` but unfortunately i m getting query string in url like this `http://localhost:53249/Admin/EditPosts?id=1&operation=Edit`

This is my actionlink(anchor tag)

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink(@posts.Title, "EditPosts", "Admin", new { id = posts.id, operation="Detail" }, null)</td>
```

This is my route config:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Admin",
             url: "Admin/EditPosts/{id}/{operation}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "EditPosts"}
         );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are mixing Action and Operation.

I suggest that you use the url like this:

```
http://localhost:53249/Admin/Posts/1/Edit
```

Because this way you already indicate your action, **Edit**, for the **Posts** objects, and **Edit** is the action, not an operation, following standard REST.

To use the url suggested you must change the MapRoute to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "Admin/Posts/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Posts", action = "Details" } //Details action by default
);
```

Comment: Thanks @guilherme but after that i am getting the url like this   http://localhost:53249/Admin/Posts/1/Posts?operation=Edit

Comment: Try with action link like this:

    @Html.ActionLink(@posts.Title, "Edit", "Posts", new { id = posts.id }, null)

Comment: but i have 2 parameter first one is id and second one is operation(edit,details)

Comment: thats the point I talked about, by concept what you are calling operation in fact should be an action, the method in the controller

Comment: operation is a parameter which is use for showing data in editable format or not and this parameter pass into the action which is renamed now to "Posts"